# how to get get license detail through office365 api?

Tags: office365

I have two kind of office365 license.

```
Office 365 Business

Office 365 Business Premium
```

And I want get license list detail, which result is below

```
Office 365 Business - WHITEBOARD_PLAN1

Office 365 Business - Microsoft Forms (Plan E1)

Office 365 Business - Exchange Foundation

Office 365 Business - Sway

Office 365 Business - Office Online

Office 365 Business - Old - OneDrive for Business (Plan 1)

Office 365 Business - O365 Business

Office 365 Business Premium - MICROSOFT_SEARCH

Office 365 Business Premium - WHITEBOARD_PLAN1

Office 365 Business Premium - MYANALYTICS_P2

Office 365 Business Premium - DYN365BC_MS_INVOICING

Office 365 Business Premium - KAIZALA_O365_P2

Office 365 Business Premium - STREAM_O365_SMB

Office 365 Business Premium - Deskless

Office 365 Business Premium - To-Do (Plan 1)

Office 365 Business Premium - Microsoft Bookings

Office 365 Business Premium - Microsoft Forms (Plan E1)

Office 365 Business Premium - Flow for Office 365

Office 365 Business Premium - PowerApps for Office 365

Office 365 Business Premium - O365_SB_Relationship_Management

Office 365 Business Premium - Microsoft Teams

Office 365 Business Premium - Microsoft Planner

Office 365 Business Premium - Sway

Office 365 Business Premium - Office Online
```

And I can not find the api after several hour search.

So somebody can help? Thank you

Comment: I have 2 licenses, Office 365 Business
And Office 365 Business Premium. Now I want to get the corresponding product information in these 2 licenses.

Comment: Or do you know the api that gets the list of licenses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you have an azure tenant. If you are asking about the API to list the commercial subscriptions that your organization has acquired, then you can use **Microsoft Graph API**. It's **subscribedSkus** API can list your subscriptions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscribedsku-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs

The Microsoft Graph API offers a single endpoint, `https://graph.microsoft.com`, to provide access to the Microsoft 365 services. You can use REST APIs or SDKs to access the endpoint.

Here the Request URL `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscribedSkus` gives a json response somewhat like:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#subscribedSkus",
    "value": [
        {
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "consumedUnits": 1,
            "id": "gf7-b578-5b71df",
            "skuId": "c7-392b571df",
            "skuPartNumber": "ENTERPRISEPREMIUM",
            "appliesTo": "User",
            "prepaidUnits": {
                "enabled": 1,
                "suspended": 0,
                "warning": 0
            },
            "servicePlans": [
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "c4806f287",
                    "servicePlanName": "INFORMATION_BARRIERS",
                    "provisioningStatus": "PendingProvisioning",
                    "appliesTo": "User"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "e95bec9d0c014",
                    "servicePlanName": "SHAREPOINTWAC",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "User"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Compare the results with the information available in https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/licenses.

You can see that for each license type,

`"consumedUnits": 1` refers to number of **Assigned** licenses

`"prepaidUnits": { "enabled": 1 }` refers to number of **Valid** licenses

Comment: Thank you very very much. I can get the skus now

Comment: Hi, last question, And I see some information here. https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/licenses .There is a table to show the use of the license.  

Name Valid Expired Assigned

Office 365 Business 25 0 3

Office 365 Business Premium 25 0 2

And which api can get this information? Thank you.

Comment: You need to just display the names of the licenses, right? When using the request URL as https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscribedSkus you are getting a lot of information. And you want only the license names to be listed?

Comment: the request URL as graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscribedSkus  show license name like O365_BUSINESS, And I see the office365 admin page, it show the name like Office 365 Business , So is there any other api that can also get the license usage?

Comment: Although I didn't get the name of the license, just like Office 365 Business - WHITEBOARD_PLAN1 and Office 365 Business Premium - Microsoft Teams, but your answer is still very helpful to me, thank you

Comment: Here are two links. I don't know whether it can help you or not. Still, have a look:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/get-a-list-of-available-licenses   and  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/users-groups-roles/licensing-ps-examples.md